# Joomla rewrite rule always 404s

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have the below rewrite rules in my .htaccess file on my Joomla installation.

```
RewriteRule ^hire/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+) /section?section=$1&sub_section=$2 [NC,L,R]
```

This works great, but I'd like to remove the R part so that it doesn't redirect, and the URL stays the nicer looking SEO friendly version. The trouble is that when I do this, I always get a 404 page.

Comment: This question relates to https://stackoverflow.com/q/67209455/2943403

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.